# SegmentedControll in navigation bar hides view.title

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a segmented control in the navigationbar in a tabbarcontroller app.

The problem is that after adding the segmented control to the navigation bar the title of my view disappears form the tabbarcontroller.

How do i work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops my bad. Adding the UISegmentedControl to the navigationbar title does not make the title disappear in the tabbar. I set the title to nil by accident when finished parsing the webpage..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the segmented Control in the right or left side not in the middle. If you will add in the middle then it will hide the title label of navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks but i wanna add it to the midle. I want a segmented control instead of the view.title in the navigationbar, but i dont want the title to disapear from the tabbarcontroller or the back button when pushing the next view.. 
Can i somehow add it ontop and keep the view.title behind it? how?